# Images are not displayed on the buttons

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, fluent

I use the Fluent Ribbon (fluent.codeplex.com). I want to arrange four buttons side by side. 
 I use the following code:

```
<Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Some Header">
    <Fluent:RibbonToolBar>
        <Fluent:RibbonToolBar.LayoutDefinitions>
            <Fluent:RibbonToolBarLayoutDefinition Size="Small">
                <Fluent:RibbonToolBarRow>
                    <Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlGroupDefinition>
                        <Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlDefinition Target="buttonFirst" />
                        <Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlDefinition Target="buttonPrevious" />
                        <Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlDefinition Target="buttonNext" />
                        <Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlDefinition Target="buttonLast" />
                    </Fluent:RibbonToolBarControlGroupDefinition>
                </Fluent:RibbonToolBarRow>
            </Fluent:RibbonToolBarLayoutDefinition>
        </Fluent:RibbonToolBar.LayoutDefinitions>
        <Fluent:Button Size="Small" Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/First_16.png" x:Name="buttonFirst" />
        <Fluent:Button Size="Small" Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Previous_16.png" x:Name="buttonPrevious" />
        <Fluent:Button Size="Small" Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Next_16.png" x:Name="buttonNext" />
        <Fluent:Button Size="Small" Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Last_16.png" x:Name="buttonLast" />
    </Fluent:RibbonToolBar>
</Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
```

The buttons are aligned correctly, but the buttons don't have a image. Where is the problem?
[image]
(The image files are available)

Comment: Just a guess - did you set the resource type of your images to 'Resource'?

Comment: Yes, the Resource type is set to `Resource`

Comment: I have the same problem.  How do I set the resource type of my image to `Resource`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to change 'Copy to Output Directory" setting. I usually use 'Always'. Or IfNewer if you have a lot and don't want a rebuild to constantly wipe and recopy.